# Java - O que fazer quando JSON pode vir em Double e em Long?

Tags: java, api

Estou utilizando uma API do ClimaTempo.

Quando pego os dados de clima de uma cidade via JSON eu obtenho a temperatura da seguinte maneira:

```
clima.setTemperatura((Long) dataNode.get("temperature"))
```

Entretanto, na documentação da API, quando uso o get("temperature") ele pode me retornar um valor "20" ou um valor "27.4", em um tipo Object. Esse valor é em graus Celsius.

Estou tendo uma exceção no java que diz que (dependendo) que:

Double não pode ser convertido para Long

O atributo `temperatura` com o tipo `Long`está na minha classe Clima.java, defini desde quando criei a classe e criei os tipos de dados no banco de dados. Então, NÃO POSSO mudar para String, pois utilizarei esse dado para fins estatísticos.

**O que devo fazer para que o tratamento se vier "20" (Long) ou "27.4" ele não ocasione essas exceções?**

**EDIÇÃO**
Como solicitaram nos comentários, vou adicionar mais detalhes.

Utilizo o seguinte método para acessar a API:

```
    @GetMapping("/clima/{idCidade}/agora")
    public ResponseEntity<Clima> getClimaAgora(@PathVariable(value = "idCidade") Long idCidade){
        JSONObject climateData = new JSONObject();
        ClimaTempoAPI ct = new ClimaTempoAPI();
        String weatherEndpoint = "/api/v1/weather/locale/"+idCidade+"/current?";
        climateData = ct.RequestWeather(weatherEndpoint);

        JSONObject dataNode = (JSONObject) climateData.get("data");     

        Clima clima = new Clima();
        clima = setClimateData(climateData, dataNode, clima);
        climaRepository.save(clima);        

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(clima);
    }
```

O erro está acontecendo no método `setClimateData` que tem a seguinte implementação na mesma classe:

```
public Clima setClimateData(JSONObject climateData, JSONObject dataNode, Clima clima){
   clima.setVelVento((Long) dataNode.get("wind_velocity"));
   clima.setDirVento((String) dataNode.get("wind_direction"));
   (...)
   clima.setTemperatura((Long) dataNode.get("temperature")  ); //Erro acontece aqui
}
```

Todos os outros `sets` funcionam sem problema algum. Só neste da temperatura que dá erro, pois pode vir tanto um numero inteiro quanto decimal.

Tentei usar o Numeric mas simplesmente não vai. Diz que não pode ser um tipo.

Já tentei algumas coisas. Como converter de Double para Long. Pegar o Object e converter para String (na hora de salvar no banco de dados da erro - estou usando Spring Boot com JPA e Hibernate). Simplesmente não tá chegando no que eu quero...

Comment: Faça cast para double somente?

Comment: E não seria melhor passar a guardar esse dado como `Double` ?

Comment: Não seria melhor sentar e chorar? De toda sorte, o retorno pelo que fala estende de `Numeric`, então é possível dar um `((Numeric) node.get("temperature")).asDouble()`

Comment: Como assim um double não pode ser convertido para long? Já tentou `Double.valueOf("27.4").longValue()`? Claro que o valor será arredondado para 27 (já que long não tem casas decimais), mas funciona. Se você puder [edit] a pergunta e adicionar exemplos de casos que dá esse erro, talvez fique mais claro (em outras palavras, um [mcve]).

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes. Tentei ser o mais resumido possível, mas precisará de mais detalhes pelo o que estou vendo.

Comment: @WitnessTruth acho que você pode tratar como `Numeric`, ambos `Double` e `Long` herdam dele. Depois a transformação é livre, com o método `.doubleValue()` ou `.longValue()`, como o hkotsubo muito bem falou

Comment: Não vai, o se eu coloco da maneira que o hkotsubo disse, simplesmente diz "Numeric cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: E se for `Number`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html Errei o nome, desculpa aí...

Comment: Qual das milhares de APIs de JSON vc está usando? Não tem nenhum método `getLong()`, por exemplo?

Comment: @hkotsubo parece JsonSimple, mas não tenho certeza

Comment: Se `get` retorna um `Object`, talvez `Double.valueOf(node.get("temperature").toString()).longValue()` funcione também. Se bem que a resposta do Victor abaixo deve resolver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o `instanceof` para saber se é `Double` ou `Long` e então escolher como tratar:

```
Object temperaturaObj = dataNode.get("temperature");
Long temperatura = temperaturaObj == null ? null
        : temperaturaObj instanceof Long ? (Long) temperaturaObj
        : ((Double) temperaturaObj).longValue();
clima.setTemperatura(temperatura);
```

Caso decida trocar para `Double` ao invés de `Long`:

```
Object temperaturaObj = dataNode.get("temperature");
Long temperatura = temperaturaObj == null ? null
        : temperaturaObj instanceof Double ? (Double) temperaturaObj
        : ((Long) temperaturaObj).doubleValue();
clima.setTemperatura(temperatura);
```

Ou então, usar a superclasse `Number` com um *cast*:

```
Number temperatura = (Number) dataNode.get("temperature");
clima.setTemperatura(temperatura == null ? null : temperatura.longValue());
```

Comment: Por que não `Number`, a classe mãe de `Long` e de `Double`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Por que no `setTemperatura`, o tipo do parâmetro é `Long`. Como ele está usando isso para fazer mapeamento JPA, não dá para usar `Number`, tem que escolher entre `Long` e `Double` (ou `BigDecimal` ou `Integer` ou `BigInteger`, etc). Mas não dá para deixar isso flexível no JPA.

Comment: `Number.class.cast(dataNode.get("temperature")).longValue()` ou `.doubleValue()`. Nesse uso, não para o tipo a ser setado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Dá para fazer mais simples que isso sem usar o objeto `class`. Editei a resposta.